# WPF asynchronous Task<T> blocking UI

Tags: wpf, user-interface, block, task

I already worked with `Task` type. And all was good while `Task` return nothing. For example:

XAML:

```
<Button Name="_button"
        Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
        Click
</Button>
```

CodeBehind:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _button.IsEnabled = false;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5*1000);
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => _button.IsEnabled = true));
    });
}
```

This works fine. But I want to `Task` returns some value, for example `Boolean`. So I need to use `Task<Boolean>`:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _button.IsEnabled = false;

    var task = Task<Boolean>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5*1000);
        return true;
    });

    if (task.Result)
        _button.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

And here we have a problem with UI blocking. UI thread is locked untill task will return result.

```
_button.IsEnabled = false;
```

So, string above is completely ignored. 
I am on `.Net 4.0`, so I cannot use `async/await` approach. 
This problem really makes me sick... Has it solution?

Comment: With [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) you can use `async/await` in .net 4.0. Make life easier:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your main thread is blocking because the call to `Task.Result` waits until the `Task` has completed. Instead you can use `Task.ContinueWith()` to access the `Task.Result` *after* the `Task` has completed. The call to `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` causes the continuation to run on the main UI thread (so you can access `_button` safely).

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _button.IsEnabled = false;

    Task<Boolean>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5*1000);
        return true;
    }).ContinueWith(t=>
    {
        if (t.Result)
            _button.IsEnabled = true;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());        
}
```

---

**Update**

If you are using C# 5 you can use async/await instead.

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _button.IsEnabled = false;

    var result = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5*1000);
        return true;
    });

    _button.IsEnabled = result;      
}
```

Comment: It works, thx :) arggghhhh! Why `Herbert Scheldt` say nothing about it in his book? Can you give me good information-source about Tasks? Except `Google` and `MSDN` of cource.

Comment: MSDN has all the information you need. See the section called Creating Task Continuations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry to revive and old Q&A, but I found your answer and this link helpful when I had this issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/18/parallel-programming-task-schedulers-and-synchronization-context.aspx

leaving it here for reference!