# Task in child window suspend UI

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, task

I have `AuthenticateWindow` and `MainWindow`, markup and code is exposed below. It is very simplified. When in the `MainWindow` constructor I use `Thread` class it works fine, but if I use `Task` class, UI is suspended, that is 'MainWindow' is not shown while `Thread.Sleep(5000);` is elapsed. Is it possible to use `Task` class (because I need its cancellation mechanism and `Status` property) without any UI suspending?

Important condition: I cannot fix code in `AuthWindow`.

AuthenticateWindow:

xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="OpenMainWindow"
            Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
</Grid>
```

c#

```
public partial class AuthWindow : Window
{
    public AuthWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DoAbsolutelyNothing()
    {

    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(DoAbsolutelyNothing).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var window = new MainWindow();
            if (window.IsInitialized)
                window.Show();

            Close();
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

MainWindow:

xaml

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="MainWindow"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

c#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Task _task;

    private void TestMethod()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Debug.WriteLine("TestMethod comleted");
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // it works badly  
        //_task = Task.Factory.StartNew(TestMethod);

        // it works fine
        new Thread(TestMethod).Start();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Windows 7, .Net 4.0

**Important: Exposed code reproduces the problem, just copy-paste!**

Comment: Define _"works badly"_ in further detail please. What are the exact symptoms of this call?

Comment: Do you call _task.Wait(); somewhere?

Comment: @ Gusdor, As I wrote above: UI is suspended, that is 'MainWindow' is not shown while Thread.Sleep(5000); is elapsed.

Comment: @George Vovos, code above has not any `_task.Wait();` and UI is suspended :(

Comment: @Gusdor, I don't quite understand waht do you mean when talk about `version`. Framework version? 4.0

Comment: why do you need the _Task variable?Your code looks ok.i think the problem is somewhere else.When you simplified the code,you missed someting

Comment: I'm interested in what the `DoAbsolutelyNothing` code does in the final version.

Comment: @George Vovos, application has the same symptoms even without `_task` variable. Could you copy-paste the code and try on your machine?

Comment: @monstr i did that...

Comment: @George Vovos, and? have you this symptom?

Comment: @Gusdor, this method really do absolutely nothing, I need it to use `ContinueWith` and `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`

Comment: Why not run it synchronously instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must force the task to run on another thread

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(TestMethod, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

More here:
[Why Starting A New Task In The Task Parallel Library (TPL) Doesn’t Always Start A New Thread](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/why-starting-a-new-task-in-the-task-parallel-library-tpl-doesnt-always-start-a-new-thread)

Comment: It works, but I thought `Task` instance runs ALWAYS in another thread by default, doesn't it?

Comment: I was under the impression that a task started using the default scheduler would always lease a ThreadPoor thread. This is very strange indeed.

Comment: That is correct.But this task was not started using the default scheduler.Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800705/why-is-taskscheduler-current-the-default-taskscheduler

Comment: Task by default runs in another thread, in your case you forced it to still work on UI thread by using TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(). What would be diffrence between synchronous method and Task if it did not run in background? Normally you use Task.Factory.StartNew(MyMethod), no need to use all this options as in accepted answear.

Comment: @Maximus You cannot guarantee that the task will run on another thread.(This is guaranteed if you use Task.Run )
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245935/is-task-factory-startnew-guaranteed-to-use-another-thread-than-the-calling-thr

Answer (score 1):

TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() creates Task not on ThreadPool Synchronization Context but on Context it is called from, in this case from UI that is why it is frozen.

Comment: And what should I do? I cannot reject TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()

Comment: Once you get rid of this it will kick of working properly. Even though you create Task it still runs synchronously on UI thread.

Comment: But then won't the code that creates the new `MainWindow` instance throw an exception as it will not be running on the UI thread?

Comment: @DanielKelley You can use the Dispatcher Object to update the UI thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602567/how-to-update-ui-from-another-thread-running-in-another-class

Comment: If you create new Window there is no need to mess around with Tasks since you have to do this on UI thread.

Comment: I was going to post this answer but was pretty sure that the `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` would run the method synchronously. Perhaps I was wrong. Is the call to `Window.Show` modal?

Comment: I cannot reject `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` because of this :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934236/wpf-asynchronous-taskt-blocking-ui

Comment: @Gusdor, it is not modal, `ShowDialog` is modal

Comment: @GeorgeVovos I'm well aware of that. The point was as it stands the answer is only half complete. You can't say "don't do Y" when that also requires "you need to do Z" without mentioning it.